# How to wake xubuntu desktop from sleep

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

I am using xubuntu 14.04 and it is connected to  a TV via VGA.

When I leave the computer for a while the screen goes blank(i'm assuming it's gone to sleep) my problem is that when I move the mouse or press a letter on the keyboard the display just won't wake up??(It could be the TV??)

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You can disable the sleep in system settings if this is helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen switches off after waking up from suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450387/screen-switches-off-after-waking-up-from-suspend)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options to avoid or recover from the issue.

Temporary fix

In the main bug ticket there's now a fix which involves adding a PPA:

Add the Xubuntu Developers PPA to get the new packages:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/ppa
```

Update package information and update the two crucial packages:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager light-locker-settings
```

xfce4-power-manager-data will get upgraded at the same time

Restart your machine.

To remove the upgrades and return your machine to it's state prior to testing

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xubuntu-dev/ppa
```

Temporary workaround

The easiest way to work around this bug is to disable lock on suspend in the light locker settings. Of course, this means that your machine will resume from suspend without a password.

Quick fix

If you end up in this situation you can get back to a working state (note that you'll lose your current session and a new one will be started) by:

Switch to a virtual terminal: CtrlAltF1

```
Restart lightdm: sudo service lightdm restart
```

[This is a known Bug and has been reported, click here to see the source of the info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450387/screen-switches-off-after-waking-up-from-suspend)